# Preparing JSON via iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am new to jquery and JSON and this is what I am trying to do.
I have a firstName field, lastName field and the list of date fields with class "actionDueDate_input".
I want to generate a JSON, which has firstName, lastName and iterating through all the date fields and inserting them into JSON.

I am trying to do the following and it is giving me "undefined". There is something basic that is going wrong here, which I am not being able to figure out.

```
var dateval="";
$('div.action input.actionDueDate_input').each(function(index)
{
    if(index>0)
    {
        dateval+=",";
    }
    dateval+="{";
    dateval+='"';
    dateval+="actionDueDate";
    dateval+='"'+":";
    dateval+='"'+$(this).val()+'"'+"}";
});

alert(dateval);

var values={"contact":
[
    {
        "givenName":givenName,
        "familyName":familyName,
        "actionSet":
        [
            dateval
        ],
    }
]};

alert('Action Dates for client one:  '+values.contact[0].actionSet[0].actionDueDate);
```

Comment: Don't construct the string manually. Just make an object and then use `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: json is not something you ever want to generate yourself. you build a NATIVE data structure (e.g. array, object..) and then have that converted to json for you by json.stringify or whatever json library you've got.

Comment: If it's giving you undefined, then certainly the issue is with $(this).val() (you didn't provide the html). I would also recommend to use JSON.stringify rather than construct JSON manually.

Comment: Do you really want to create JSON or just an array of objects?

Comment: @FelixKling, I need the user object with the "firstName", "familyName" and "actionSet", which is the collection of dates. Now this collection of dates is where I am thinking of iteration. Basically, I want to construct an "user" object that has x number of "action" objects. I am happy to adopt any way which is recommended.

Comment: Ok, but it does not sound like you need JSON. I mean, build the data structure first, and then you can always easily convert it to JSON afterwards with `JSON.stringify` if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

JSON takes the form of a specially formatted string, not an array. An array is what you get when you parse JSON.

To JSONify an array, use `JSON.stringify(arr)`.

Here's an example that takes all the values of a primitive form and bundles them into a JSON string:

```
var formInputs = {},
    jsonString;

$('form').find('input', 'select').each(function(){
    formInputs[this.name] = this.value;
});

jsonString = JSON.stringify(formInputs);
```

Comment: If `this.name` is not numeric, then this won't work. You have to use an object: `formInputs = {}`.

Comment: whoops, meant to use curly brackets, not square brackets. Thanks.